# Java RegEx Search Value

Tags: java, regex

Any ideas on how could I get the values from the labeled below text using REGEX on Java Platform. If my regex search was involved the two words of "Demo and Name", I could get the line of "Name: John Doe". If my regex search was involved the two words of "Demo and Address", I could get the value of "Address: Home".

```
Comment Section

    Comment: This is the comment for Comment Section
    Another Field: This is for another field

Another Comment

    Comment: This is comment for another comment

Demo

    Name: John Doe
    Address: Home
```

Comment: What are you wanting?

Comment: It's really unclear what you want to achieve. Please elaborate.

Comment: What I want is to get the line of word when having a search on the text using REGEX. Just imagine that those text above was written on XML format. So, If I want to get the "John Doe", The targeting node is Demo->Name. Something like that, but I want it on REGEX.

Comment: @NappaTheSaiyan Can i achieve this process by using the REGEX? Because Im trying to use the look behind, look ahead but still no luck.

Comment: @Mark refer to my answer

Answer (score 1):

This pattern works for name

```
Demo\s*|.*Name: (.*)
```

Test it here http://regexpal.com/

If you are using Java you will most likely be reading the input file one line at a time. If that is the case you need to set a flag when Demo pops up then check for a line containing "NAME:". Set flag off when closing DEMO tag pops up.

Comment: the patterns works fine, but how could I get the value of "Name: John Doe" like what has been highlighted on the sample runner

Comment: Anything between () is captured which means in this case "John Doe" will be captured. If you want "NAME: John Doe" then move the start of the parenthesis to before "Name"